# What does $0=$1 mean in awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

Let's say, I have an input text file (sample_simple.txt) like this:

```
3 1 10 1 6
9 4 2  4 1
9 2 2  2 1
```

By using the command: `awk '$0=$1" "$1*$2" "$3*$4' sample_simple.txt`, I get the following output:

```
3 3 10
9 36 8
9 18 4
```

Then using the command: `awk '$1*$2" "$3*$4' sample_simple.txt`, nothing changes from the input file:

```
3 1 10 1 6
9 4 2  4 1
9 2 2  2 1
```

The only change between the commands is `'$0=$1'`, Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Someone was apparently trying to play golf and in doing so created the least clear version of that script possible. The obvious, clear way to write a script to do what that convoluted nightmare is trying to do is just `awk '{print $1, $1*$2, $3*$4}' sample_simple.txt`

Comment: @cutrightjm How is that related? It's not merging rows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not really `$0=$1`; think of it more like

```
$0 = ($1" "$1*$2" "$3*$4)
```

So

```
$0=$1" "$1*$2" "$3*$4
```

assigns the result of string concatenation `$1" "$1*$2" "$3*$4` to variable `$0` and performs the default action `{print $0}`, whereas

```
 $1*$2" "$3*$4
```

concatenates the results of `$1*$2` and `$3*$4` (with a space `" "` between) and performs the default action `{print $0}` because the result is a non-empty string. The value of `$0` is not modified.

Comment: It looks nicer if you just set `OFS=" "` and use `$3*=$4`, `$2*=$1`.  Setting `$1` is not necessary as it doesn't change. Also note that `$1" "$1*$2" "$3*$4` is the same as `($1) " " ($1*$2) " " ($3*$4)` (with or without parentheses).  The unquoted spaces could be used to show that the `" "` are just concatenations with spaces.

Comment: Maybe it would be more clear if you added another two pairs of parentheses `$0 = ($1 " " ($1*$2) " " ($3*$4))`. The fact that string concatenation (eg. `a b`) has lower precedence than multiplication in awk is not some obvious law of nature ;-)

Comment: I think this answer is better with the addition of a single set of parenthesis, as this highlights what the OP missed, adding further parentheses would make clearer code, but would be a worse answer.

Answer (score 8):

in awk

- `$0` is whole line
- line can be changed on the fly

thus

- `$1" "$1*$2" "$3*$4` create 3 fields `$1` ,  `$1*$2` and `$3*$4`
- `$0=` the result is put to the line, and <s>implictly printed</s> (see edit).

Edit :

If you omit `$0=`, ouput line is not changed.

As Steeldriver pointed out, since search is positive, line is prinetd.